# Can you validate whether a user has been recently authenticated on Firebase (Swift)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to check if a user has recently authenticated on Firebase to avoid this message when trying to delete a user: *"This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request."*

I have been playing around trying to compare lastSignInDate (below) to current time but there seems to be a large margin of error on this which can cause problems:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInTime
```

Are there any functions that can return a simple boolean as to whether a user has recently authenticated so the user.delete() function will work properly?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you use Cloud Functions in Firebase?

Comment: The idiomatic way to deal with sign-in recency is to catch the error you get back from the API call. Trying to pre-detect the condition is not recommended.

Comment: Fully understood Frank, the only slight issue is that I'm looking to delete Firestore entries on user deletion but if I wait for the error on the API call to define whether or not to delete the entries it is then not possible to delete them (because of the Firestore security rules that require authentication).

How do you suggest best to do this? Is it a case of writing a Cloud Function?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is by checking if the response has an error, like so:

```swift
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
user.delete { error in
  if let error = error {
    if (error.code == "auth/requires-recent-login") {
      // The user's credentials are too old. Prompt Login screen.
    }
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user), There's no other approach to this other than comparing the current date with `firebase.auth().currentUser.metadata.lastSignInDate` (Only if you have the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/UserMetadata) on your app, but you most probably do not need that for enabling a user to delete themselves).